# Meaning of Hannah's last appearance

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the last episode of season 7, we see Hannah McKay leaving a black flower at Dexter's door.

What does it mean?

Will she try to kill him or was it a goodbye-gift meant to symbolize her sadness that he betrayed her? Or is it something else?

Comment: I fear we may not know the answer until next season, but at the very least, maybe someone with more floral knowledge can interpret what might happen from what kind of flower it was.

Answer (score 6):

[From the executive producer](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/dexter-season-8-spoilers-dexter-deb-laguerta-scott-buck-403148) (Scott Buck) :

> Buck: It was a very dark shot, but it was a black orchid, which is meant to be a very ominous sign from Hannah that Dexter would understand what it meant.